# JavaScript getJSON returning duplicate values in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I am trying to parse a json result but I keep getting duplicate values in my array. It seems like the code is running twice . Here is my code any feedback would  be appreciated

```
var channels = ["ESL_SC2", "OgamingSC2", "cretetion", "freecodecamp", "storbeck", "habathcx", "RobotCaleb", "noobs2ninjas", "brunofin", "comster404"]
var clientID = "######";
var allChannels = [];
var feedReturn = [];
$(document).ready(function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < channels.length; i++) {
        allChannels[i] = channels[i];
        //allChannels[i][0] = channels[i]
        $.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/" + channels[i] + "?
            client_id = sbp1wnku2j32dtnjj4qefhslopxq8s ",function(data){
            $.each(data, function(i) {
                if (data.stream == null) {
                    feedReturn.push(["Null", data._links.channel]);
                } else {
                    feedReturn.push(["Not Null", data._links.channel]);
                }
                //console.log(data.stream);
                // console.log(data._links.channel);
                //feedReturn.push(data.stream,data._links.channel);
            })
        })
}
});
console.log(feedReturn);
```

Comment: What troubleshooting has been done and what is the question?

Answer (score 1):

You are calling `$.each()` on the `data` object, which will return an array with a length equal to the number of properties on that object. Since the API data returned has two properties (_links, stream) it will run the `.push()` 2 times for every API call. Simply removing the `$.each()` will solve your issue with duplicate records in your array.

```
$.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/streams/"+channels[i]+"?client_id=sbp1wnku2j32dtnjj4qefhslopxq8s",function(data){
  if(data.stream == null){

    feedReturn.push(["Null",data._links.channel]); 

  } else {

    feedReturn.push(["Not Null",data._links.channel]);
  }
});
```